# Find Any string contains List<>

Tags: linq

I'm trying to find a string from the List....seems like its not working and if I have just `List<string>` it does work.. meaning like the below code...

```
    List<string> c = new List<string>();
    c.Add("John Doe"));
    c.Add("Erich Schulz"));
```

//I think the problem with the Criterion class?
here is my class structure:

```
public class Criterion
{
    public Criterion(String propertyName, object value)
    {
        this.PropertyName = propertyName;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

//here is the method...
public static List<Criterion> LoadNames()
{
    List<Criterion> c = new List<Criterion>();
    c.Add(new Criterion("Name1", "John Doe"));
    c.Add(new Criterion("Name2", "Erich Schulz"));
    return c;
}
```

here is the code I'm trying to make it work:

```
bool isExists = LoadNames.Any(s=> "Erich Schulz".Contains(s));
```

Error:

does not contain a definition for 'Any' and the best extension method overload `'System.Linq.Enumerable.Any<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,bool>)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: What do you expect `"Erich Schulz".Contains(s)` to call?

Comment: i'm checking to see if the name exists or not.

Comment: Probably just a typo, but you are trying to call Any on your method and not on the List it returns. You need to do LoadNames().Any(...).

Comment: Your Criterion class is incomplete. Where are the two properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to compare a string to a Criterion object, which just doesn't work.

Here is the fixed code:

```
bool isExists = LoadNames.Any(criterion => String.Equals(criterion.PropertyName, "Erich Schulz", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `.Contains(s)`, `s` isn't a string, it's `Criterion`. Use `.Contains(s.propertyName)`.

```
bool isExists = LoadNames().Any(s=> "Erich Schulz".Contains(s.PropertyName));
```

Also you're using LoadNames as a method, you need to execute it first.